# What rules/declarations do I need to add to a CSS class to enable word wrap with no single-word truncation?

Tags: html, css

I have a piece of html like this:

```
<div id="prizeCategory" class="category">Applications</div>
```

The category CSS class is:

```
.category {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Consolas, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: Orange;
    max-width: 180px;
}
```

I want to keep this section of HTML to a maximum width, and thus enabled word wrap of the 
`#prizeCategory` value ("Applications" in the example above), but since I've added a max-width, it gets truncated to "Applicatio"

I need the value to word wrap when multiple words, but ignore that max-width and show the complete value if it won't fit otherwise. IOW, a value of "Application" should show the full text of "Application" on one line, but a value of "Applied History" on two lines, as:

```
Applied
History
```

IOW, most of the hmtl5 sections will be the same width, but some will be longer to accommodate a long single word as the value of the "prizeCategory" element.

I wonder if I will have to count the length of the #prizeCategory element's value each time, and change some properties/use a different class based on that length (kind of like an "internal media query")?

jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/zhTNS/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JQuery:

```
    $(function () {
      while ($('.category span').width() > $('.category').width()) {
        $('.category span').css('font-size', (parseInt($('.category span').css('font-size')) - 1) + "px");
      }
    });
```

Your updated HTML:

```
<div id="prizeCategory" class="category"><span>Applications</span></div>
```

I added a `<span>` to your code.

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gxg1974/xk2C6/)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware you can't do this.

`max-width` does its job. It will not let you exceed the bounds you set. You have the choice of breaking your word (`word-wrap: break-word;`), setting a larger `max-width`, or falling back to JQuery/Javascript to define your custom rules.

Comment: I only want to break the phrase if they exceed the general width I want. IOW, I wouldnt' want to break on every word in the phrase "If I was a bee" - however, I would want to break on "Involuntary Cowslaughter" or "Involuntary Cows Laughter" ("Involuntary" on the first line, "Cows Laughter" on the second line).

Comment: I see. Then break-word won't help you, but either way my answer stands. You cannot do this with just CSS.